# how to print logs from windows native in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, plugins

I am developing plugin with Native Windows C++ code. The problem is my app crashing many times but I can't see any logs from C++ side. How can I see logs of my application crash for this?

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you check Windows Event Viewer logs, sometimes it collects crashes.

Comment: I need more flutter like way as It looks quite tricky and not much informative for me

Answer (score 1):

It was quite tricky one. But I used this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkAhFhcLn9Q) video which helped me a lot in how to debug. Thank you Indian guys).

Also, to print logs in c++ Flutter I used this code:

```
OutputDebugString(L"This debug is worth an upvote;)");
```

To print a variable:

```
OutputDebugString((L"My C++ debug: " + winrt::to_hstring(iAmStringVariable) + L"\n").c_str());
```